# Jquery Ui dialog button changes position on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, stylesheet

I am using jquery ui dialogue and adding buttons using jquery like this:

```
 $("#151").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                autoResize: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        jQuery(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
                ,
                open: function () {
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("OK")').focus();
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("OK")').addClass('customokbutton');
                }
            });
```

and custombutton class looks like this:

```
.customokbutton { 
    text-indent: -9999em; /* hides the text */
    color: transparent; /* also hides text */
    background-image: url(images/login-icon.png); /*replaces default image */
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-color: transparent;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    cursor: pointer;  
    border:none;
    height:30px;
    outline: none;
}
```

but when I bring mouse on button, it goes a bit down and right. I see using Firebug that following css classes are added when i bring mouse away ( changes position )

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only customokbutton" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">OK</span></button>
```

and this one when i hover over button:

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only customokbutton ui-state-hover" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">OK</span></button>
```

and css is like this:

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    border: 1px solid #707070;
/*  background: #dadada;*/
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #212121;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: give us a working example of your code using something like jsfiddle

Comment: And how is the `ui-state-hover` class is defined in the jquery ui css?

Comment: @Tallmaris Please check updated question for css

Comment: Yup, it may be the border itself which is causing the shift. See the answer for a possible fix...

Comment: Did this issue ever get resolved?  I see no solution in this thread but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the theme but seemingly the `ui-state-hover` in the jQuery CSS has a 1px border:

```
border: 1px solid #fbcb09;
```

css is here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css

Maybe that is what is shifting the button 1px right and down. You can try enforcing the `border: none;` property in your CSS, like this:

```
.customokbutton { 
  [...]
  border:none !important;
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Mmmm... can you create a quick working fiddle? I tried and it seems to be working ok: http://jsfiddle.net/QbuT3/

Comment: I am sorry I can not produce the fiddler as my css file is too long and i dont know which style is effecting this. How can I force the button to be at same place ?

Comment: You can use the Chrome debugger and add the `ui-state-hover` manually yourself so you can investigate what styles are being applied.

Comment: What Styles should I add in ui-state-hover to make the button at same position ?